# ReverseGeocodeQuery does not return correct information

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, reverse-geocoding

I created a class to do Reverse Geocode.

```
    public static class ReverseGeoCoding
    {
    public static ObservableCollection<string> Addresses = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public static string Address;


    public static Task<MapAddress> DoReverseGeoCodingAsync( GeoCoordinate location )
        {
        MapAddress mapAddress = null;

        var reverseGeocode = new ReverseGeocodeQuery
                                 {
                                     GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate( location.Latitude, location.Longitude )
                                 };

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<MapAddress>();
        EventHandler<QueryCompletedEventArgs<System.Collections.Generic.IList<MapLocation>>> handler = null;
        handler = ( sender, args ) =>
                      {
                          if ( args.Error != null )
                              {
                              tcs.SetException( args.Error );
                              }
                          else if ( args.Cancelled )
                              {
                              tcs.SetCanceled();
                              }
                          else
                              {
                              if ( args.Result.Count > 0 )
                                  {
                                  var firstOrDefault = args.Result.FirstOrDefault();
                                  if ( firstOrDefault != null )
                                      {
                                      mapAddress = firstOrDefault.Information.Address;
                                      }
                                  }

                              reverseGeocode.QueryCompleted -= handler;
                              tcs.SetResult( mapAddress );
                              }
                      };

        reverseGeocode.QueryCompleted += handler;
        reverseGeocode.QueryAsync();
        return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
```

As I call it the first with (35, -112 for example) is that only the country and the country code (USA) are shown. The second time I am calling this function the data returned is full as expected (Williams, AZ 86046).

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Investigating more into the issue I found out the following:

The location (GeoCoordinate) is taken from the center of a map on the page. If the map is zoomed (ZoomLevel) to less than 10, I find this issue happening, and if the map is zoomed to more than 10 it works OK. Not sure why it is happening. Any Idea? Somebody else noticed that?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the whole collection, not just the first result?

Comment: Yes, of course, however the result has only one address.